# What are intransitive verbs with dative complement called?

Tags: terminology, verbs, grammatical-object

First off, I was about asking this question on [German Language & Usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/) since this is a feature specific to the German language. Possibly, this feature exists in other languages as well but as far as I know not in English. Anyway, since this question is about linguistics I think this is the right place.

From what I know, transitivity, in linguistics, means whether or not a verb is followed by a direct object (called accusative in German). *To thank*, for example, is a transitive verb.

> *I thank.
>
> I thank you.

In contrast, an intransitive verb must not take a direct object. *To die* is such a verb.

> *He died something.
>
> He died.

<sub>(In addition, respective to comments: *[To die](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die)* is defined as intransitive by Merriam-Webster dictionaries but it seems to be ambitransitive, too, because *to die a death* is valid transitive use of *to die*.)</sub>

Some verbs can be followed by a direct object but this object is not necessary. These verbs are called ambitransitive. As example, consider the verb *to eat*.

> I am eating.
>
> I ate an apple.

And some transitive verbs additionally have a second object, the indirect object (dative in German). The appropriate term is ditransitive.

> *I give.
>
> *I give you.
>
> I'll give you a chance.
>
> I'll explain it to you.

Since the indirect object is the recipient of the direct object the indirect object can't be defined independently from an direct object, at least in English.

> *I give to you.

In German, however, you can put a dative object behind some intransitive verbs. *Danken* (English *to thank*) is one of those verbs.

> Ich danke dir.

In comparison to *I thank you*, *dir* is not an accusative in German and consequently not a direct object. I'd claim that in German it is possible to use an indirect object without a direct object.

To cut a long story short: what is the appropriate term for intransitive verbs which take an indirect object or dative, respectively, though?

---

Regarding comments:
I don't understand the discussion about the definition of transitivity. In the German sentence *Ich danke dir* the verb *danken* is intransitive. I think Dixon's definition is not relevant to this question. Of course, if it were *the definition par excellence* then *danken* would be transitive but before posting this question my research gave no inkling that I had to doubt whether *danken* is *intransitive* since it has no accusative object and that's the *most accepted* definition.
(Perhaps some linguistics will disagree. I'm not very familiar with linguistics but there's one rule I follow in general: If even experts don't agree then I stay with the most accepted definition until someone gives a persuasive counterargument.)
That said, sources that handles the German language only, and therefore using the terms accusative and dative object rather than direct and indirect object, mentions that a verb in its transitive form has to be followed by an accusative object.

That said, in the sentence above *danken* is intransitive. @jlawler confirms this when saying "Transitivity is not a property of verbs per se, but of verbs in a particular sentence -- or perhaps, better, only of sentences" although I think he actually wanted to say the opposite.

So, these discussion might be interesting but are unrelated to my question:  what are verbs called that are intransitive and followed by an dative object as *danken* in *Ich danke dir.*

Comment: Your final question is a bit unclear... Are you asking how to call verbs that take a D.O. with the Dative instead of using the traditional Accusative?

Comment: @Alenanno Well, I'm aware of that some doubts may raise whether the dative object is still the indirect object if no accusative exists. But I think we still talk of the recipient, although the information what they receives is missing. For that reason, I'm asking for a name for verbs which take no direct object at all but are followed by an indirect object.

Comment: Even if the direct object is not accusative it's still a direct object. It's not that case that makes it D.O., rather its role in the sentence. In Russian, singular male accusative goes to genitive singular (if I remember correctly) but it's still direct object.

Comment: Usually it's not verbs that are either transitive or intransitive but rather particular verb meanings.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, I don't agree on that. A transitive verb takes a direct object. An intransitive verb does not. That's the definition, isn't it? The German word *danken* is an intransitive verb and as such it can't take a direct object. For this reason, whatever you place behind *danken* it is not a direct object, not at all.

Comment: I'm afraid things are much more complicated. Usually transitivity is defined semantically and not structurally - e.g. Dixon defines transitivity as "involving two obligatory participants" or Naess 2007 "a construction with two syntactically privileged arguments."

Comment: Transitivity is not a property of verbs per se, but of verbs in a particular sentence -- or perhaps, better, only of sentences. To say that X is an intransitive verb and therefore cannot take an object is to get it backwards -- if X can't **ever** take a direct object, then it's intransitive; but evidence, and lack of counterexamples, is required. Labels do not change structures. And in English just about every "transitive" verb can occur "intransitively" in speech, and vice versa.

Comment: I've seen "dative verbs."

Comment: _Mir wurde geholfen_?

Comment: @jlawler Your last comment would be an indicator to cast doubt on dative object being regarded as an indirect object but still is not an argument to call it direct object instead. Same issue with genitive objects or prepositional objects. There seems to be no agreement on whether or not those objects are considered as indirect object. I heard the term *oblique object* but not sure if that has any relation to those objects. Anyway, what I just want to say is that there's a lack of ultimate definition. - And I'm simply looking for a term for specific intransitive verbs.

Comment: @AlexB. Yes, me too, but I don't know if that's what he's looking for.

Comment: The terms "direct object" and "indirect object", like "the phoneme /i/", are subject to variation from language to language. German has a dative case and there are verbs with dative objects; this is a fact. English does not have case at all and distinguishes direct from indirect object covertly. But I'm still not sure what you're asking about. If you're referring to [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) followed by Passive, as in _Bill was given an extra ticket_, that's a construction and only the B-Raising part is governed by specific verbs.

Comment: "my research gave no inkling that I had to doubt whether danken is intransitive." More details, please.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first these verbs are not really *intransitive*. We call them **indirect transitive verbs**. They exist not only in german but in french too. Examples : *dépendre de*, *appartenir à*, *obéir à*, *plaire à*, *téléphoner à*. Contrary to english, in french we cannot reverse these constructions to the passive voice (*I **was given** a present*).

These verbs can even be doubly indirect transitive verbs. For example in french *je **t'**ai parlé **d'elle***. This is the *case* — pun intented — in german too.